# How to make a trained neural network "forget" an instance?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, predictive-models

I am using neural networks for predicting the behavior of a dynamic system. A neural network is trained online using snapshots from the system's past. The system changes its state at irregular intervals, and whenever this happens a *part* of the past training instances become invalid. I can detect the change in the state and also identify the invalid instances. The question is how can I make the trained neural network "unlearn" or "forget" some instances?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type of Neural Network you are using. A single layer Perceptron could do this by subtracting the eta value from each node the number of iterations you trained on based on the activated or not activated features and outputs.

If you are using any optimization techniques like early stopping however it wont make sense since the network was dynamically adjusted during training. If you want to incorporate or exclude data from your training set, I would instead go with an unsupervised learning model like KNN, or save the data and re-train the network using something like early stopping to optimize the outputs for the next version of the model without the instance of data you are attempting to "forget"

Comment: In the case of a linear regressor (or ELM, in the neural context), how is the numerically stable way to forget/unlearn an instance? Is it enough to increment training with a negative output?

Comment: KNN is lazy, not unsupervised.